# How does adding a 3rd party logging service affect how much i have to pay to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, heroku, splunk

This would sound very newbie but I've just added a centralized logging service (Splunkstorm free version) to my rails app on heroku and it completely changed my life. I don't know why i never thought of this before.

I can just read all the logs from web interface without running `heroku logs --tail` which spawns a new dyno everytime i do it.

Which makes me curious: Does adding this type of logging service affect how much i have to pay to heroku? I mean, it's sending out packets every time something happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope!

Bandwidth is included in the dyno pricing (including the one you get for free).

There is [a soft limit at 2TB of bandwidth](https://www.heroku.com/policy/aup), but you're unlikely to come anywhere near that from logging.